# sum up values of a column depending on 2 other values ​from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis

I'm using jupyter notebook to visualize some data with python.
I got a dataframe with following columns: matchid, player, visionscore, win

[given table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqbDW.png)

Now i want to sum up the visionscore. For every matchid there are 10 entries given, which go from player 1 to 10 (player 1-5 = team 1, 6-10 = team 2) and each player has it's own visionscore.
Now i want to have something like this:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kivPc.png)

Obviously im new to data analytics. I allready have a table where the visionscore/matchid is summed up, but unfortunately there is no seperation between the teams. So it's the whole visionscore for the game.

[table i allready got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilXfz.png)

Comment: Please update your post with raw data using `df.to_clipboard()`.

Comment: where is teams in your sample dataframe? do you need to merge that on ?

Comment: i have a version of the dataframe where i got an extra column with team, sorry forgot to post that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I randomly generated data, but I think this should work.

```
df['team'] = [1 if p<=5 else 2 for p in df.player]
df.groupby(['matchid', 'team'])['visionscore', 'win'].sum()
```

---

```
matchid team    visionscore win
10      1       274         3
10      2       124         3
11      1       416         3
11      2       89          0
```

Comment: how about ```df['team']=df['player'].gt(5).add(1)``` :)

Comment: win get's also summed up. Now i need to drop any value in column "win" which isn't 0 or 5 since 0 means lose and 5 means win.
How can i say that in python? My brain always thinks in java :/

Comment: try `df.loc[df.win.ne(0) & df.win.ne(5)]`. `.ne()` means `not equal to`, so it should select all values inside of `win` column that don't equal to 0 and 5